# WCF : How to detect a session is timeout?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-security

I write this Interface to create and terminating a session.

```
 [ServiceContract(SessionMode = SessionMode.Required)]
  public interface IOrdersService
  {
    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = true, IsTerminating = false)]
    void EmptyCart();

    [OperationContract(IsInitiating = false,IsTerminating = false)]
    void AddToCart(CartItem cartItem);
   }
```

it`s work fine. But when a session timeout then how can i detect ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is trimmed out, your channel will be faulted both on your client and your server's callback channel, you can listen on faulted event on channel. And once it is faulted, you will need to recreate a channel to recover.